# RandomStringUtils generate similar values in one run. How to generate different?

Tags: java, variables, random, testng

I have a problem.
In one test run i generate random numeric variable (but has String type) in every test. 
Im using a RandomStringUtils lib for that.

But it generates only one value of that variable for all of tests. How to generate **new value** in every test?

Example:

```
public void test() {
    JsonResponse response = dosomething(baseUrl(), generateId());
    assert something
}
```

and generateId() method in other class

```
public static String generateId(){
        return RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(6);
    }
```

the whole test suite looks like (and i got equal all of generateId() values) :

```
public class Tests {
public void test1() {
        JsonResponse response = dosomething(baseUrl(), generateId());
        assert something
    }

public void test2() {
        JsonResponse response = dosomething(baseUrl(), generateId());
        assert something
    }
}
public void test3() {
        JsonResponse response = dosomething(baseUrl(), generateId());
        assert something
    }
```

apache version is 3.7 (its in external libs)

```
Export-Package: org.apache.commons.lang3;version="3.7",org.apache.comm
 ons.lang3.arch;version="3.7",org.apache.commons.lang3.builder;version
 ="3.7",org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent;version="3.7",org.apache.c
 ommons.lang3.event;version="3.7",org.apache.commons.lang3.exception;v
 ersion="3.7",org.apache.commons.lang3.math;version="3.7",org.apache.c
 ommons.lang3.mutable;version="3.7",org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect;v
 ersion="3.7",org.apache.commons.lang3.text;version="3.7",org.apache.c
 ommons.lang3.text.translate;version="3.7",org.apache.commons.lang3.ti
 me;version="3.7",org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple;version="3.7"
```

Comment: How does your whole test suite look like?

Comment: @syntagma i'd added to question

Comment: Which version of Apache Commons? How are you running the tests (CI, locally, docker container, VM etc.)?

Comment: @jannis apache 3.3.7, locally

Comment: Where do you take it from? Give us a link or maybe a Maven/Gradle dependency snippet. I cannot find version 3.3.7 in Maven Central: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

Comment: @jannis i did a mistake. Version is 3.7

Comment: Just tested and works for me. I created a testclass with three tests. Every of them reports a different result from `generateId`.The problem must be somewhere else in your code. You'll need to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you.

Comment: I would suggest using secure random: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and have got different numbers in each test.

You can see through the RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(final int count) calls and find that there is following code:

```
random(count, start, end, letters, numbers, null, RANDOM);
```

Possible, you have issues with Random that is very strange. Anyway, you can try to call it with your own Random object. Do not forget to create Random objects with different **seed** numbers.

Comment: i had tried your idea with using random frorm StringUtils....Yes, it works. But...how. I dont understand what problem do i have

Answer (score 0):

[RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) is deprecated

> as of 3.6, use commons-text RandomStringGenerator instead

Use the following replacement code example:

> ```
> // Generates a 20 code point string, using only the letters a-z
> RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
>  .withinRange('a', 'z').build();
> String randomLetters = generator.generate(20);
> ```